# How do I remove (Dell printer) drivers from the cache so I can re-intall from the CD

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, installation, printer

I have a Dell All-in-One 810 printer from years ago and only recently installed it (a few months ago).

Later I had reason to uninstall and re-install the printer but whenever I connect the printer Windows installs the printer drivers from its cache without the CD.

How can I remove all traces of the drivers from the cache so that it will install only from the CD and not from the Windows driver cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I could find, there is a removal tool for the drivers which is to remove incomparable drivers prior to upgrade to Vista. This should work just fine for what you are trying to do.

[Removal Tool](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/04/DriverDetails?driverId=R166125)

Once that is done, I would suggest downloading the latest drives rather than running the installation CD. This will ensure you have any driver updates which came out after the OEM CD was shipped with the printer.

[Dell 810 Drivers](http://downloads.dell.com/Pages/Drivers/dell-810-all.html)